# StartActivityForResult for multiple buttons accessing one activity and getting different datas on selection?

Tags: java, android, android-cursor, start-activity

I'm developing an app in which one of its features is to allow the user to input a phone number or select one from the phones contacts.

The activity has 3 `EditTexts` along with 3 `Buttons` each on the side, and the buttons open the Contacts `Activity` and return the selected phone number and sets the `EditText` accordingly.

I have tried setting separate `cursors` for each `button`.
 I have also tried using different `intent` variables.

**My problem:** When the user selects the contact to get data from, the cursor returns a different number. Either it returns the contact next to it or the contact previously selected.

The `OnClick` method for the **3 buttons** with `startActivityForResult`.

```
//The intent
i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);

public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

        case (R.id.button1):
        startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        break;

        //I know it's an ImageView
        case (R.id.imageView1):

        startActivityForResult(i, 1);
        break;

        case (R.id.imageView2):

        startActivityForResult(i, 2);
        break;

        }
    }
```

The `OnActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {


    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode){

    case (0) :
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
              Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                     c.moveToFirst();
                    contact1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                    et.setText(contact1);

                }
            break;

    case (1) : 
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Cursor c1 =  getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                     c1.moveToFirst();
                    contact2 = c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                    et2.setText(contact2);


                }
            break;
    case (2) : 
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Cursor c2 =  getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
                 c2.moveToFirst();
                contact3 = c2.getString(c2.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                et3.setText(contact3);

            }
        break;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change `Phone.CONTENT_URI` to `intent.getData();`

```
Uri contactData = intent.getData();
Cursor c =  getContentResolver().query(contactData, null, null, null, null);
```

what you are doing wrong is querying each time the exact same query without regard to the `intent` result...so of course you will get the same result each time

Also because you want to get the phone number add a `projection` value:

```
String[] projection = {Phone.NUMBER};
getContentResolver().query(contactData, projection, null, null, null);
```

to better understand please read [how to get contact phone number](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: Hm, now I'm getting an IllegalStateException(Couldn't read row 0) for the cursors. What does it mean?

Comment: it means that your column index is incorrect... run `c1.getColumnNames()` and print for yourself all the columns that are returned, use one of them...

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to call multiple startactivityforResult in Android, it only called the first declared on startactivityforResult, I resolved this issue by making a function with startActivityforResult and passing the intent and requestcode to the function that contained startActivityForResult.